# Hausdorff Product of 2 nonempty spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need help with the following proof. Would be thankful for any help.

> If $X, Y$ are nonempty topological spaces. Given the $X \times Y$ is Hausdorff, show that $X$ and $Y$ each are Hausdorff spaces.

I tried to look at given points $x_1, x_2$ in $X$ with $x_1 \ne x_2$ and $y_1, y_2$ in $Y$ with $y_1 \ne y_2$. Then I used the definition of the product topology and the Hausdorff property of $X \times Y$, to find open neighborhoods $U_1 \times V_1$ of $(x_1, y_1)$ and $U_2 \times V_2$ of $(x_2, y_2)$, $U_1, U_2$ open in $X$ and $V_1, V_2$ open in $Y$. Then I used the Hausdorff property to say that the intersection of $U_1 \times V_1$ and $U_2 \times V_2$ is empty. This also means $(U_1 \cap U_2) \times (V_1 \cap V_2)$ is empty. This means either $U_1 \cap U_2$ or $V_1 \cap V_2$ is empty. I can't really figure out how to prove that if $U_1 \cap U_2$ is empty and $V_1 \cap V_2$ is not empty, that $Y$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried to look at given points x1,x2 in X with x1≠x2 and y1,y2 in Y with y1≠y2. Then I used the definition of the producttopology and and the Hausdorff property of X x Y, to find open neighboorhoods U1 x V1 of (x1,y1) and U2 x V2 of (x2,y2) U1,U2 open in X and V1,V2 in Y.  Then I used the Hausdorff property to say the the intersection of (U1 x V1) and (U2 x V2) is empty. This is also means (U1 n U2) x (V1 n V2) is empty, n being the intersection symbol. This means either U1 n U2 or V1 n V2 is empty. I cant really figure how to prove that if U1 n U2 is empty and V1 n V2 is not empty, that Y

Comment: is Hausdorff. Or for the analog case.

Comment: You should include those details in the body of your question, so that your question is better-received.

Comment: oh yes my bad, im so stuck on this problem, that i completely forgot.

Comment: The trick, as in @K.Jiang's answer is that for $(x_1, x_2) \ne (y_1, y_2)$ it's enough to have either $x_1 \ne x_2$ or $y_1 \ne y_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_1 \ne x_2 \in X$. Consider any $y \in Y$. Since $X \times Y$ is Hausdorff, there exist disjoint basis elements $U_1 \times V_1, U_2 \times V_2$ of the product topology such that $x_1 \times y \in U_1 \times V_1$ and $x_2 \times y \in U_2 \times V_2$. By definition, $U_1, U_2$ are open in $X$ and $V_1, V_2$ are open in $Y$. We claim that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are disjoint. Suppose not. Then there exists $x_0 \in U_1 \cap U_2$, and $x_0 \times y \in (U_1 \times V_1) \cap (U_2 \times V_2)$, contrary to the hypothesis that $U_1 \times V_1$ and $U_2 \times V_2$ are disjoint. Since $x_1 \ne x_2$ were arbitrary, $X$ is Hausdorff.

A very similar argument applies to show that $Y$ is also Hausdorff.

Comment: this makes alot of sense, thank you for your help. could one also prove in the way i tried to, or is the approach insensible?

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea. A few comments: a neighborhood of the point $x \times y$ in $X \times Y$ under the product topology *need not* be of the form $U \times V$, where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ open in $Y$. However, since these sets form a basis for the product topology, Hausdorffness implies the existence of disjoint *basis* elements containing unequal points (you should prove this if you have not seen it). Then, it is true that $(U_1 \times V_1) \cap (U_2 \times V_2) = (U_1 \cap U_2) \times (V_1 \times V_2)$. Since $V_1 \times V_2 \ne \emptyset$, then $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$.

Comment: oh yes i just wrote it down how my professor does in his lectures, i should have mentioned that U x V form a basis for the product topology. Im not sure if I understood the last part of your comment, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I made a typo; it should be $V_1 \cap V_2 \neq \emptyset$ rather than $V_1 \times V_2 \neq \emptyset$ (which is nonsensical). According to my choice of points $x_1 \times y$ and $x_2 \times y$, and disjoint basis elements $U_1 \times V_1$ and $U_2 \times V_2$ containing them, then $y \in V_1 \cap V_2 \implies V_1 \cap V_2 \neq \emptyset$. Since $(U_1 \times V_1) \cap (U_2 \times V_2) = (U_1 \cap U_2) \times (V_1 \cap V_2) = \emptyset$, and $V_1 \cap V_2 \neq \emptyset$, then it must be the case that $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$, which is what want to show.

Comment: Alright I figured so, but was not sure if it was the case. I understand what you mean. I guess I should have tried to prove Hausdorffness for X and Y individually. Or rather I don‘t know how to do it, if I dont assume y in Y as an arbitrary fixed point. Nevertheless thank you so much for your help, it was really insightful.

Comment: Could you kindly assist me in identifying any logical errors in the following reasoning? If I follow the same approach as described in my first statement, then $(U_1 \cap U_2) \times (V_1 \cap V_2) = \emptyset$. And then I consider the 3 cases:
i) $(U_1 \cap U_2) = \emptyset$ and $(V_1 \cap V_2) \neq \emptyset$
ii) $(U_1 \cap U_2) \neq \emptyset$ and $(V_1 \cap V_2) = \emptyset$
iii) $(U_1 \cap U_2) = \emptyset$ and $(V_1 \cap V_2) = \emptyset$

Comment: Next, let's consider case i). Can't I define $U_1 \cap U_2$ as $U$, and say that with $x_1 \neq x_2$, $U_1 \setminus U$ is a neighborhood of $x_1$ and $U_2 \setminus U$ is a neighborhood of $x_2$, in particular, $U_1 \setminus U \cap U_2 \setminus U = \emptyset$? Therefore, $X$ is a Hausdorff space.

Comment: And let U1 × V1 be a neighborhood of (x1, y1) in X × Y, and let U2 × V2 be a neighborhood of (x2, y2) in X × Y.

Comment: No. Just because $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open, does not mean that either $U_1 - U_2$ or $U_2 - U_1$ are open.